# How do I sort based on a value from a 1-to-1 dependency

Tags: mysql

How do I sort foo's based on bar.val

```
create table foo (id, name)
create table bar (id, foo_id, val)
```

foo has 1-to-1 relationship with bar
and some foo's will **not** have bar's

```
insert into foo (1, 'A');
insert into bar (1, 1, 'Active');

insert into foo (2, 'B');
insert into bar (2, 2, 'InActive');

insert into foo (3, 'C');
// 3 doesn't have a bar

insert into foo (4, 'D');
insert into bar (3, 4, 'InActive');
```

Comment: not too clear, what you want to achieve

Comment: Is the description clear now?

Comment: @Rpj Please let me know if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, b.val
FROM foo f LEFT JOIN bar b
ON f.id = b.foo_id
ORDER BY COALESCE(b.val, 'Archived') DESC
```

For those `foo` records which do not have a corresponding record in the `bar` table, they will be assigned a default value of "Archived" for the purpose of ordering the result set.

Comment: Is there a way treat the NULL values with a default value say "Archived"

Comment: Use the `COALESCE` function.  In the event that `val` be `NULL`, it will be replaced with `"Archived"`.

Comment: will give you suggestion a try and let you know.